# 2 SQL queries in one try/catch. Not working

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Basically, I have to show a list with the data from a database table [that part is working] and afterwards I have to show the highest Date [a date variable in the table]. The second part is not working no matter what I do.

Here's the code

```
try {
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM tb_rafael";

        ResultSet rs = BD.consultar(SQL);

        String tab = "";

        int numReg = 0;

        while (rs.next()) {
            tab+="<TR>";
            tab+="<TD>" + rs.getString("nme_rafael") + "</TD>";
            tab+="<TD>" + rs.getString("dta_rafael") + "</TD>";
            tab+="</TR>";
            numReg++;

            //mDat = rs2.getString("dta_rafael");
        }

        rs.close();

        dados.put("DADOS", tab);
        dados.put("NUM_REG", String.valueOf(numReg));


        //Pegar Data Maior
        String SQL2 = "SELECT MAX(dta_rafael) FROM tb_rafael";


        ResultSet rs2 = BD.consultar(SQL2);
        String mDat = "";

        //while(rs2.next()){

            mDat = rs2.getString("dta_rafael");

        //}
        rs2.close();

        dados.put("MDA", mDat);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        dados.put("MSG", "Erro: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
```

What you want to look at is past the commentary line "Pegar Data Maior". That's the part that is not working. I've tried adding a while, using a different `ResultSe`t, using the same `ResultSet` and none of those worked. I know it's not an issue with the SQL query since I tested it with the workbench and it returned me the data I want.

To be more specific, I don't get an error message or anything, the `dados.put` simply does not work and I get just this:

[image]

How the HTML code looks:

[image]

The data should show up where the `{MDA}` is. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: must be `while(rs2.next()){

            mDat = rs2.getString("dta_rafael");

        }`
debug your program and see what you are getting  `mDat`

Comment: Why did you comment `'//while(rs2.next()){'`...??? unless use `next` it would through an error.

Comment: I debugged and for mDat I'm getting: >no current context(stack frame)<

By the way, if this matters I'm using Netbeans 7.2, because my uni uses that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query `SELECT MAX(dta_rafael) FROM tb_rafael` may not return a column name, which you later try to retrieve, `rs2.getString("dta_rafael");`
I'd change the query to `SELECT MAX(dta_rafael) AS Max_date...,` and reference to `MAX_date` thereafter.

Comment: Yes, that should probably works. Also, you can try mDat = rs2.getString(1);

Comment: Thank you soooooo much. I didn't even think of trying that. What I did was instead of rs2.getString("dta_rafael") I used the column name that showed up in the workbench when I ran the query so the result was rs2.getString("MAX(dta_rafael)") and it WORKED.